# Image texture not showing up on glossy material

Tags: rendering, image

I added a material to an object, put a gloss bdsf on it and for color i selected image texture. I selected an image and it's not showing up when i click render. What should i do?

[image: material tab]

[image: texture tab]

Comment: Is it showing up in the rendered view of the viewport though? Also, have you set it to UV coordinates and unwrapped it, or set it to use generated coordinates with a texture coordinate node?

Comment: How are you mapping the texture? If you don't give the image coordinates or a UV map then you are just going to get a solid color

Comment: it's not showing in the rendered view and no, i haven't unwraped it because i'm not sure how to do it

Comment: Depending on the roughness, glossy materials will reflect the environment. If the roughness is too low you will not see much of the object (and texture) itself. A higher roughness will reveal the texture. Unfortunately you did not add any images to help us understand what you have and what you expect to get, but it sounds to me that you need a diffuse shader that is using an image texture mixed with a glossy shader.

Comment: i added a uv map and now it's showing the texture

Answer (score 1):

I think there is some issue with unwrapping.
Check this method:

1. Select that object and enter into EDIT MODE.
2. Now select the whole object By pressing A key ( u need to press it twice to deselect and select whole object in edit mode)
3. Then press U key and select "UNWRAP"
4. No go to UV editor and check whether u have unwrapped the image correctly onto the image texture.

This should work else, ping me back!